# Attach item to a user

Tags: php, mysql

Im looking to create a site that will attach a piece of media to a user.

So for example if a user has watched a new movie, they can click on the movie and have that added to there profile as being watched.

I have two databases for users and movies, each has an Id, but im not sure how to attach the movie to the users profile? i know requires a join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have three tables (all in one database):

`users`: `userid`(primary),`name`(unique),...

`movies`: `movieid`(primary),...

`watched`: `userid`(index),`movieid`(index)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a "Users" table and a "Movies" table, what you would probably need is a table in between, say, "MoviesUsers", to join the two.

MoviesUsers would have two fields: movie_id and user_id, and each row in this table would represent the attachment between a user and a movie.

You need this table because this is a many-to-many relationship: each user can have many movies, and each movie can be attached to many users.

Hope I have been able to help.